# Installing netflix, terminal is getting hung up

Tags: installation, command-line, netflix

Just got Ubuntu up and running, I am attempting to follow the steps laid our [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/130372/how-to-watch-netflix-on-ubuntu-with-the-netflix-desktop-app/)  to install Netflix via Wine.

I have done the 3 terminal commands, and I believe the package has downloaded.

The commands:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ehoover/compholio
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install netflix-desktop
```

After this the terminal spits out a user agreement, and I cannot get past this.  Is there some way to minimize the window within the terminal?  This is what I see:

[image: screenshoot].

Netflix is not yet in my dash.  It also appears that a variety of other updates are being held up, I assume, because my terminal is midthought.

Comment: That is a normal *windows* inside a terminal, where you can see a lot of information and also you have button to press. Have you tried using the arrows keys or the mouse to choice the *ok* button?

Answer (score 0):

That is not a Window but an actual display in the Terminal window where you are installing Netflix. It can't be bypassed. You have to agree to the user agreement before you can install the Proprietary software that Netflix requires. Just hit the arrow keys, tab, or pageup/pagedown, until the "OK" is selected(I forget which keys are exactly the ones you need to press since it's been a while since I installed). Now press enter and the Installation should continue.

In the future ask the Developer directly on his Webpage for help. He often replies quite quickly, or many people in the comments probably already had your issue and have already gotten replies.

http://www.iheartubuntu.com/2012/11/ppa-for-netflix-desktop-app.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I could select and click to agree to the terms, but the window would always say I hadn't agreed to them.

I found the following workaround:

1. Uninstall Netflix
2. Install mscorefonts on it's own
3. Install Netflix again

I've done this two or three times (different systems) with no issues. Hopefully this works  for you as well.

Cheers!